# Jquery Datepicker not shown up on click of p:inputText inside p:tab in primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am using jquery datepicker for primefaces calender.I just created a p:inputtext and calling the jquery datepicker on it. This datepicker is calls up when I am putting the p:inputtext **outside of p:tab** but it is not shown up when I am putting p:inputtext **inside of p:tab**.

JQuery Function :

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $('.calenderType').calendarsPicker();
});
    </script>
```

1) Input text on which calender is working fine:

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td><p:inputText value="#{gen.appInitDate}" id="appInitDate"
                maxlength="100" onchange="changeEVENT();"
                disabled="#{gen.disableGen}"  class="calenderType">
        </p:inputText>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

2) Input text on which calender is not wokring :

```
    <p:tab titleStyle="font-weight:bold" title="#{lang.gen_info}" id="genInfoTabId"
        titleStyleClass="collapsible" >
    <p:panel id="geninfop" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p:inputText value="#{gen.appInitDate}" id="id1"
               maxlength="100" onchange="changeEVENT();" 
               disabled="#{gen.disableGen}" class="calenderType">
            </p:inputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
            </table>
        </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

</p:accordionPanel>
```

Basicallly in the 2) scenerio p:inputtext is inside the p:tab so any jquery fucntion is not calling up on it due to which jquery calender is not working.Please suggest some solution for this.

Comment: 1) why not use the PF calendar? 2) [mcve], is the tab lazy?

Comment: @Kukeltje... I need Hijri calender which is not available in PF..

Comment: PrimeFaces uses jquery calendar.... So if there is some extension to enable Hijri in the jquery calendar, you can use it in primefaces too...

Comment: @Kukeltje...I want to use   [keith-wood-Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.HTML). Please suggest how can I use this plugin with p:calender..

Comment: Afaics, this is a new plugin and not an extenstion of the 'standard' jquery calendar plugin and hence not an extension and hence not usable with p:calendar.

Comment: @Kukeltje...agree with you..Could you please help me in find out that why the jquery function posted in question is not able to fire for scenario 2) but able to fire for scenario 1). I have checked out and found that If i Remove the p:tab from the code posted for scenario 2) ; than in scenario 2) also I am able to fire that jquery fucntion...

Comment: **_[mcve] and is the tab(view) lazy?_**

Comment: Sorry, no time for real time chat

Comment: @Kukeltje... Yes Tab view is lazy as it is loading the data when we are clicking on it..

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje...Got the point,it is bcs of lazy loading.. Can we achieve this with lazy loading or some way for it...

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by changing the jquery code as below:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.calenderType').calendarsPicker();
        setInterval(function(){
            $('.calenderType').calendarsPicker();},100);
});
    </script>
```

Just called that function for every 0.1 seconds and it works..

Comment: Bad solution (like fighting a mosquito with an F-22), but since you did not post a [mcve] or version info, it is difficult to help with a good/better solution